# KO: can't setup redirection, port probably used by another program on host

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, telnet

I'm referring [this simple tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) to develop a client-server communication between 2 emulators.

I'm getting stuck here:

[root@seng-eucalyptus platform-tools]# telnet localhost 5554 Trying

::1... telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused Trying

127.0.0.1... Connected to localhost. Escape character is '^]'. Android Console: type help' for a list of commands 
OK

***redir add tcp:5000:6000***

***KO: can't setup redirection, port probably used by another program on
host***

What I've done so far:

1) Instead of '***tcp***', I tried '***udp***'. Connection was OK, but the service did not work.

2) In xinetd.conf, I've added the lines to redirect the port nos 5000 & 6000 from the IP addresses of the emulators to to address 127.0.0.1

10.0.2.15 5000 127.0.0.1 5000
10.0.2.2 6000 127.0.0.1 6000

3) Restarted xinetd service

Surprisingly, the solutions on stackoverflow did not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It magically worked by interchanging the ports.

So, instead of writing

redir add tcp:**5000:6000**

I wrote

redir add tcp:**6000:5000**

Of course, I changed the port nos in my client.java and server.java too.

Why did this work ? How ? I don't know. **This is paranormal Android activity.**